# Other protocol except HTTP which are used in JAVA socket?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

Is there only used TCP or HTTP protocol to request/respond from server/client? If there other have, how use them?

Answer (score 0):

TCP and UDP are opposed，not is HTTP.
Usually，HTTP contains TCP and UDP